# how to retrive a qty of product from a specific cart in soap client2?

Tags: cart, api, soap, ce-1.8.1.0

please help me out. I am adding a product to a cart using `cart_product.add` (SOAP V1) with a qty-2. But when a retrieve a `cart_product.list` at that time I am not getting a qty. So how can i get the qty of product of cart?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `cart.info` api call it contains all information about cart and cart items.

More you cat read in [manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html).